# python преобразовать число в расстояние

Tags: python, поиск-библиотек

Что имеется в виду.
Вот пример для перевода числа в `timestamp`:

```
import time

result = str(time.strftime('%H:%M:%S', time.gmtime(12345)))
print(result)    #   03:25:45
```

Есть ли аналогичное решение ('родное' из какой-нибудь библиотеки или кастомный сниппет) для перевода числа в расстояние? В любом формате: `'км:м:см'` или список значений `[км, м, см]`.

Искал по запросам типа `'convert integer to distance'` но ничего не нашел.

Comment: сделайте сами с помощью целочисленного деления и остатка от деления

Comment: Тут про гигабайты, но подчерпнуть вдохновение можно https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1094841/get-human-readable-version-of-file-size

Comment: Не понятно зачем для хранения расстояния какой-то отдельный тип. Вам скорее всего нужно не "преобразовать в расстояние", а вывести число с нужным форматированием. Что-то типа `print(f"{int(distance) // 1000} км {int(distance) % 100} м {int(distance * 100) % 100} см")`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Такую функцию не сложно написать. Есть вот такой вариант:

```
def convert_dis(x):
    km = x // 100000
    m = (x % 100000) // 100
    cm = x % 100

    return f"{km} км : {m} м : {cm} см"

distance = 100000 ## сто тысяч см = 1 км;
result = convert_dis(distance)

print(result)
```

Answer (score -1):

```
def format_distance(distance, unit):
    units = {
        'meters': ('метр', 'метра', 'метров'),
        'kilometers': ('километр', 'километра', 'километров'),
        'miles': ('миля', 'мили', 'миль')
    }

    if unit not in units:
        raise ValueError("Недопустимая единица измерения")

    forms = units[unit]

    if distance == 1:
        return f"{distance} {forms[0]}"
    elif 1 < distance < 5:
        return f"{distance} {forms[1]}"
    else:
        return f"{distance} {forms[2]}"

# Пример использования
distance = 3
unit = 'kilometers'
formatted_distance = format_distance(distance, unit)
print(formatted_distance)
```

Comment: Вы точно поняли смысл вопроса?